# Mapping Wikipedia links to pages

Tags: c#, api, mediawiki, wikipedia

I'm using the MediaWiki API to extract links from a Wikipedia page.
The following query is used to extract links from Albert Einstein's page:

```
string query = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Albert%20Einstein&prop=links"
```

I'm using C# to produce this query, via an HTTP GET command:

```
string responseInfo = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(query);
```

My question is: How can I map the links to actual Wikipedia pages? For example, the link "Absorption refrigerator" maps to the web page "Absorption_refrigerator". How can I determine this programmatically? Can I **always** assume that a white space maps to an underscore?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert%20Einstein is a valid URL that will get you to the Albert Einstein article (through a 301 redirect). Isn't that enough for you?

Comment: @svick, what I need are the links (to other Wikipedia articles) inside that page. I am trying to avoid unnecessary parsing of html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia **ALWAYS** processes white spaces as underscores